# Drawing an distribution of measurments in an XY plan

Tags: normal-distribution, graphing-functions, variance, covariance, means

I have a localization problem where I got 100 measurements of x and y points.

From these points, a mean and matrix of covariance were calculated, from which, I extracted the individual means and variance for x and y. Now I need to plot an approximation of the distribution of these measurements in an XY plan.

At first, I thought there would be 2 Gaussian distributions summed together but not knowing the actual measurements I can't draw them. Then I realized I need to draw an ellipse-like graph based on the mean on the x-axis with the spread of its variance and the same on y. But how could I do that? I found an image [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhrNR.jpg) of how it should look but I don't know how to get to these shapes based on my means and variances